# What's wrong with the `root` in the BST Program?

Tags: c, recursion, data-structures, structure

I have learned about the implementation of BST in C.

Here is the code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct tree{
    int data;
    struct tree *left;
    struct tree *right;
};


struct tree *newnode(int );
struct tree *insert(int , struct tree *);
void inorder(struct tree *);

int main(){

    struct tree *root = NULL;
    root = insert(5, root);
    root = insert(3, root);
    root = insert(4, root);
    root = insert(2, root);
    root = insert(7, root);
    root = insert(6, root);
    root = insert(8, root);
    root = insert(9, root);



    printf("\nInorder Traversal : \n");
    inorder(root);

    return 0;
}

struct tree *newnode(int data){
    struct tree *new = (struct tree *)malloc(sizeof(struct tree));

    new->data = data;
    new->left = NULL;
    new->right = NULL;

    return new;
}

struct tree *insert(int data, struct tree *root){
    if(!root){
        printf("For %d\n",data);
        root = newnode(data);
    }

    else if(root->data >= data ){       /* Push this into left subtree */
        printf("Else if : For %d\n",data);
        root = insert(data, root->left);
    }

    else{                       /* Push this into left subtree */
        printf("Else : For %d\n",data);
        root = insert(data, root->right);
    }
    return root;
}

void inorder(struct tree *root){
    if(root){
        inorder(root->left);
        printf(" %d",root->data);
        inorder(root->right);
    }
}
```

Whenever, I run the program, I don't get the desired output. That is, the above code should print something like this :

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

But it prints `9`, and that is it.

I have checked the code thoroughly, going through all possible corner cases, it seems fine to me.

The recursion function `insert` looks perfect. But, somehow, the `root` pointer is always pointing to the last node inserted.

Can you point out the mistake? I have been trying since past 1 hour.

Comment: Step through the code, all of it, line by line in a debugger. Stepping into each of the `insert` calls and into the recursive `inorder` calls. Make sure it works as it's supposed to do. Please also read [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: I don't know C too well but in your elseif and else case of insert do you not want to just call insert, not assign it to root?

Comment: @NickA You're close, very close. An assignment of the returned pointer is needed, but not to `root` itself.

Comment: @SomeProgrammerDude I did step through each `insert` call. And it works perfectly fine!

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude ahhh to root->left and root->right respectively?

Comment: @NickA Yep, that should solve it. :)

Comment: Got it @Someprogrammerdude!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Someprogrammerdude for pointing out.

In the `insert` function, I should have done this :

```
struct tree *insert(int data, struct tree *root){
    if(!root){
        root = newnode(data);
    }

    else if(root->data >= data )        /* Push this into left subtree */
        root->left = insert(data, root->left);

    else                        /* Push this into left subtree */
        root->right = insert(data, root->right);

    return root;
}
```

So, `root->left` and `root->right` is important for assignments.